# IDEA An error window without information appears

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ide, jetbrains-ide, intellij-14

When I get any error I get thrown to this window (see below)
[image]
As you can see in the screenshot, there is no information there at all.

**Is there any way to configure it to throw an error (as in the screenshot)**. Attaching a screenshot
[image]

Comment: The difference between the two screenshots is the tree item you've selected in the tree on the left. You simply have to select the root item to see the full output, though I also find it annoying it doesn't do that by default. Or are you aware of this, and are asking if there is a setting so that it _does_ select the root item by default?

Comment: the message itself tells you what to do to get the stacktrace. Have you tried that?

Comment: The error itself does not bother me. I would like it to select the root of the error, so that I don't have to switch manually every time

Answer (score 1):

According to the question asked on intellij-support forum [1] about the same feature, this is **currently not possible**, but there is opened usability issue [2] (issue found in discussion for [1]).

---

[1] https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360010646559-Configuring-how-the-Run-tab-displays-groups-errorsCurrently

[2] https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-241844?_ga=2.126381837.1225666940.1640705394-2133216003.1622795053